# @media Orientation Width

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-orientation

When specifying `min-width` and `min-device-width` media queries, is the width you declare based off the current width of the phone or the potrait width of the phone?

For example, an iphone4 has a width/height of 320x480 in standard/portrait orientation and has a `device-width` of 320. If the phone is held in landscape, is the `device-width` now 480 or is it still 320?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width that is used will be the current width of the viewport. If the orientation rotates, the current width will change to be the width of the rotated device (or, the height of the device in portrait mode).

You **can** specify the orientation, using `orientation: landscape`.

See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Also just found this link which states that for both iphones and ipad, when using 'device-width' the width in reference is always the portrait width, regardless of orientation. Using 'width' on the other hand, corresponds with the current orientation width.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Answer (score 1):

It’s always the “current” width. You can easily check this by alerting `window.innerWidth` or something similar.

Example:

```
+---------+    +-----------------------+
|         |    |                       |
|         |    |       480 x 320       |
|   320   |    |                       |
|    x    |    |                       |
|   480   |    +-----------------------+
|         |                 Width: 480px
|         |
|         |
+---------+
Width: 320px
```

A rotation also fires a `resize` event.

But an important note: if you don’t have a viewport meta tag like one of these then another width is used (e. g. 980px) which stays the same for both orientations:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Only with one of these two meta tags the width adapts to the orientation.